# How to Generate dynamic arraylist in java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I need to get dynamic arralylists of arraylist. I have a arraylist derived from myTable using findAll method. It gives some list values stored in table and makes an arraylist like findAllArraylist.

ex.

```
List<Model> findAllArraylist= myDAO.findll();
```

Then, I am making an array to store a single element value from findAllArraylist, using for loop as follows,

```
int[] myIntArray = new int[];         
for (int i= 0; i< findAllArraylist.size(); i++) {   
      int val = findAllArraylist.get(i).getMemberCount();
      myIntArray.add(val);      
  }
```

Then, I am removing duplicates of myIntArray, using LinkedHashMap. So, If I have a redundant values of a column in that list, it should be filtered and unique.

```
myIntArray= new ArrayList<Integer>(new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(myIntArray))
```

Now, I have only single values of member count if they are more in findAllArraylist.

Ex.

```
myIntArray[1,2,5,5,1,2,5,1,2,5,5,1,2,5]
```

should be

```
myIntArray[1,2,5]
```

Now I need to create more arraylist based on myIntArray values. If myIntArray size is 3 I have to make 3 arraylists,  If myIntArray size is 10 I have to make 10 arraylists.

I am using if statement to make arraylists as like below under the for loop of findAllArraylist,

```
    for(int i = 0; i< findAllArraylist.size();i++){
        Model temp = (Model) findAllArraylist.get(i);

        if(myIntArray.size()==3){
            List<Model> arraylist1= new ArrayList(Model); 
            List<Model> arraylist2= new ArrayList(Model); 
            List<Model> arraylist3= new ArrayList(Model);   

            if (findAllArraylist.get(i).getMemberCount()== myIntArray.get(0)) {
                arraylist1.add(temp);
            }
            if (findAllArraylist.get(i).getMemberCount()== myIntArray.get(1)) {
                arraylist2.add(temp);
            }
            if (findAllArraylist.get(i).getMemberCount()== myIntArray.get(2)) {
                arraylist3.add(temp);
            }
        }

        if(myIntArray.size()==2){
            List<Model> arraylist1= new ArrayList(Model); 
            List<Model> arraylist2= new ArrayList(Model); 

            if (findAllArraylist.get(i).getMemberCount()== myIntArray.get(0)) {
                arraylist1.add(temp);
            }
            if (findAllArraylist.get(i).getMemberCount()== myIntArray.get(1)) {
                arraylist2.add(temp);
            }
        }

        if(myIntArray.size()==3){
            List<Model> arraylist1= new ArrayList(Model); 

            if (findAllArraylist.get(i).getMemberCount()== myIntArray.get(0)) {
                arraylist1.add(temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have to make it as single code as dynamic creation of the arraylists. Can anyone give me an idea on how to do this.

I did a sample here.. http://jsfiddle.net/L6Lqafue/

Comment: The sample code here contains compilation error. Please give the actual code. For example:

int[] myIntArray = new int[];
List<Model> arraylist1= new ArrayList(Model); 

Will not even compile.

Comment: Sorry, Now it is cleared... http://jsfiddle.net/L6Lqafue/2/

Answer (score 0):

May be you try to use `Map` instead of `List`

```
        Map<Integer, Model> map = new HashMap<Integer,Model>();

       for(int i = 0; i< studlist.size();i++)
       {
             Model temp = (Model) findAllArraylist.get(i);
           for(int j=0; j<myIntArray.size(); j++)
            {
              if (findAllArraylist.get(i).getMemberCount()== myIntArray.get(j)) 
                {
                    map.put(j,temp)//Insert elements with `J` index as you check them with `myIntArray`
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: How may I access them. Reference to my question, I would like to get arraylist1 or arraylist2 and print them using System.out.print();

Comment: I need to save them each as a variable and need to show them as a separate list....... I followed this solution and the sample is here http://jsfiddle.net/o0jvc5jy/

Comment: So you got what you want .. ?

Comment: No, Still I cant get the grouped arraylists.... Thats what I asked for.. I need to get the arraylist1 as Student("1726", "John", 1), Student("7765", "Sam", 1), Student("3442", "Mark", 1).....arraylist2 as Student("4321", "Max", 3), Student("2234", "Andrew", 3)..... and arraylist3 as Student("5223", "Michael", 4)

Answer (score 0):

The body of the for-loop that you have can be transformed into a loop statement as follows:

```
List<List<Model>> myLists= new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i< studlist.size();i++){
        Model temp = (Model) findAllArraylist.get(i);

        for(int j = 0; j< myIntArray.size(); j++){
            List<Model> arraylist= new ArrayList<Model>();
            myLists.add(arraylist)
            if (findAllArraylist.get(i).getMemberCount()== myIntArray.get(j)) {
                arraylist.add(temp);
            }
        }
}
```

In this way the previously created lists that you were hard coding are added to myLists.

Comment: How may I access them. Reference to my question, I would like to get arraylist1 or arraylist2 and print them using System.out.print();

Comment: I cant actually save the separate arraylists for each myIntArray.size().  Sample is here http://jsfiddle.net/aw8f2nc6/

Comment: The arrayLists are saved in myLists.

Comment: myLists contains all the list values, but I need to get id 1 values as separate list and id 3 values as as separate list also  id 4 values as separate list......